# Adding ViewBox control reference to Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight-toolkit

I have a requirement to use ViewBox control in my SilverLight project. Googled & found need installation of Silverlight Tool Kit for downloading dlls(Microsoft.Windows.Control.dll). As per the instructions i have downloaded tool kit from (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). But when i tried to reference the dll(Microsoft.Windows.Control.dll) in my silverlight project i didnt find that dll. I tried even searching in my entire system. In some other blogs its mentioned as to reference (System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll) to get ViewBox control. I did the same but not able to get ViewBox control in my XAML code. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Using VS 2010 IDE,Version 4.0 & XPProfessional OS.

Thanks
Ganesh.B

Answer (score 0):

The Viewbox is found in System.Windows.dll it moved...

I had the exact problem just now and fixed it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=VS.95).aspx

David Gray Wright